# How do i get the LifecycleOwner for livedata object that is not in an activity

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-livedata

I am trying to overwrite a firebase message and I need to use a live data object in a class that is not in an activity but i dont know how to get the LifecycleOwner.

```
        currentUserIDLiveData.observe(this , androidx.lifecycle.Observer{
            println("THE CURRENT USER ID IS " + it)
        })
```

Comment: That depends. Are you trying to get the lifecycleOwner of a Fragment, a Dialog, a random class like a Manager, or what exactly?

Comment: Afaik `FirebaseMessagingService` does not extend `LifecycleService`, so you can use `observeForever` on your `LiveData` and remove the Observer in the Service's onDestroy.

Comment: If you use ``observeForever``, make sure you create an ``Observer`` object that you hold onto, and pass in when adding and removing the observer. If you use a lambda it gets converted to a SAM, which is treated as a different object each time, so the original one doesn't get removed and you end up with memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to observe it forever and it doesn't matter for you that it could cause memory leak or not, you can use observeForever method of liveData. But if it's necessary to pass the lifecycleOwner and you are not in a common owners like activity and fragment, you should implement your custom lifecycleOwner based on it's base interface and pass it to liveData as well. It's not too hard to implement it, just you have to know when your component is alive and when it's not.